# GlassFish JDBC Realm Troubleshoot jdbcrealm.grouperror

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbcrealm, glassfish-4.1

**What do i want to achieve:**
Only users with the role "head" should access to any path that matches the pattern "mario/*"

**What is my scenario:**
There two roles: "head" and "default". The role "head" is mapped to the group name "HEADS". The role "default" is mapped to the group name "USERS". Every logged user is assigned this last group according to my jdbc realm configuration.

I assigned the groups "USERS, HEADS" to the user with email "robert@example.com"  and then tried to login. Login was successful, but the user was only assigned the role "USERS". *The problem is that The user is not being assigned the role "head".*, CAUSING A 403 HTTP RESPONSE. What is wrong?

**Attempt to fix**

I went to my jdbc realm configuration and changed the value of the 
input filed labeled with "Assign Groups:" to the following: "USERS,HEADS".
This made every logged user be assigned both groups. This is not what i wanted. I changed the realm configuration again and set the "Assign Groups" value to "USERS".

**What the Server logs tell me:**
jdbcrealm.grouperror

**What is my JDBC realm configuration:**
[image]

**My glassfish version: 5**

**The Role Mapping:**

```
 <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>head</role-name>
        <group-name>HEADS</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>

    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>default</role-name>
        <group-name>USERS</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
```

Security constraints definitions:

```
  <security-constraint>

        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Restricted</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/mario/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>head</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

    </security-constraint>

 <security-constraint>

        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Everyone user can access</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>default</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

    </security-constraint>

   <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>default</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

My Database: modified from https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxgo.html

```
 CREATE TABLE "FOREST"."PERSON"
(
  ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
      (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  FIRSTNAME varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  LASTNAME varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL varchar(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  ADDRESS varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  CITY varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PASSWORD varchar(100),
  DTYPE varchar(31)
)
;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SQL_PERSON_EMAIL_INDEX ON "FOREST"."PERSON"(EMAIL)
;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SQL_PERSON_ID_INDEX ON "FOREST"."PERSON"(ID)
;
CREATE TABLE "FOREST"."GROUPS"
(
   ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
       (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
   NAME varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   DESCRIPTION varchar(300)
)
;
CREATE TABLE "FOREST"."PERSON_GROUPS"
(
  GROUPS_ID int NOT NULL,
  EMAIL varchar(45) NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE "FOREST"."PERSON_GROUPS"
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_GROUPS_PERSON
FOREIGN KEY (EMAIL)
REFERENCES "FOREST"."PERSON"(EMAIL)
;
ALTER TABLE "FOREST"."PERSON_GROUPS"
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PERSON_GROUPS_GROUPS
FOREIGN KEY (GROUPS_ID)
REFERENCES "FOREST"."GROUPS"(ID)
;
CREATE INDEX SQL_PERSONGROUPS_EMAIL_INDEX ON "FOREST"."PERSON_GROUPS"(EMAIL)
;
CREATE INDEX SQL_PERSONGROUPS_ID_INDEX ON "FOREST"."PERSON_GROUPS"(GROUPS_ID)

INSERT INTO "FOREST"."PERSON" (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,ADDRESS,CITY,
PASSWORD,DTYPE) VALUES ('Robert','Exampler','robert@example.com',
'Example street','San Francisco','81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055',
'Customer');
INSERT INTO "FOREST"."PERSON" (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,ADDRESS,CITY,
PASSWORD,DTYPE) VALUES ('Admin','Admin','admin@example.com','Example street',
'Belmont','81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055','Administrator');
INSERT INTO "FOREST"."PERSON" (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,ADDRESS,CITY,
PASSWORD,DTYPE) VALUES ('Jack','Frost','jack@example.com','Example Blvd',
'San Francisco','81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055','Customer');
INSERT INTO "FOREST"."PERSON" (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,ADDRESS,CITY,
PASSWORD,DTYPE) VALUES ('Payment','User','paymentUser@dukesforest.com',
'-','-','58175e1df62779046a3a4e2483575937','Customer');

INSERT INTO "FOREST"."GROUPS" (NAME, DESCRIPTION) 
VALUES ('USERS', 'Users of the store');
INSERT INTO "FOREST"."GROUPS" (NAME, DESCRIPTION) 
VALUES ('ADMINS', 'Administrators of the store');
INSERT INTO "FOREST"."GROUPS" (NAME, DESCRIPTION) 
VALUES ('HEADS', 'The God Users');

INSERT INTO "FOREST"."PERSON_GROUPS" (GROUPS_ID,EMAIL) 
VALUES (1,'robert@example.com');
INSERT INTO "FOREST"."PERSON_GROUPS" (GROUPS_ID,EMAIL) 
VALUES (3,'robert@example.com');
INSERT INTO "FOREST"."PERSON_GROUPS" (GROUPS_ID,EMAIL) 
VALUES (2,'admin@example.com');
INSERT INTO "FOREST"."PERSON_GROUPS" (GROUPS_ID,EMAIL) 
VALUES (1,'jack@example.com');
INSERT INTO "FOREST"."PERSON_GROUPS" (GROUPS_ID,EMAIL) 
VALUES (1,'paymentUser@dukesforest.com');
```

Comment: The problem may be the configuration of PERSON_GROUPS table. The foreign key should be the PERSON id, not the email.

Comment: Thats not the problem. I pulled that database schema from oracle's website. Follow the link and see it by urself. It is supposed to work. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxgo.html)

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? I have already saw the oracle website.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm currently having the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with your groups setting in one of the following locations

1. Web.xml => authorization  setting for the security constraint
2. Glassfish-web.xml => Specifying  the group name for the roles
3. Database => group name specified in your groups table